# How do you reference an array item within nativeArrray<Entity> in ECS

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-dots, unity-ecs

I'm trying to do the following:

```cs
private void AssignPlayer()
{
    EntityQuery playerQuery = GetEntityQuery(ComponentType.ReadOnly<PlayerTag>());
    Entity playerEntity = playerQuery.ToEntityArray(Allocator.Temp);

    Entities.
        WithAll<ChaserTag>().
        ForEach((ref TargetData targetData) =>
        {
            if (playerEntity != Entity.Null)
            {
                targetData.targetEntity = playerEntity;
            }

        }).Schedule();
}
```

But the line that assigns `targetData.targetEntity = playerEntity;` throws the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Unity.Collections.NativeArray<Unity.Entities.Entity>' to 'Unity.Entities.Entity'

Comment: I'm trying to assign one follower to one leader

Comment: `NativeArray<Entity> playerEntities = playerQuery.ToEntityArray(Allocator.TempJob);`
`Entity playerEntity = playerEntities[0];`
`playerEntities.Dispose();`

Answer (score 1):

```cs
if( playerQuery.CalculateEntityCount()!=0 )
{
    NativeArray<Entity> players = playerQuery.ToEntityArray( Allocator.TempJob );
    Entities.WithName("targetData_update_job")
        .WithReadOnly( players ).WithDeallocateOnJobCompletion( players )
        .WithAll<ChaserTag>()
        .ForEach( ( ref TargetData targetData ) =>
        {
            targetData.targetEntity = players[0];
        }
        ).ScheduleParallel();
}
else Debug.LogWarning($"{nameof(AssignPlayer)}(): no players tho");
```